# How do I make sure that docs apps script doesn't finish the entire task in one go?

Tags: google-apps-script

So i'm trying to program an Ascii animation with apps script but there doesn't seem to be a way to add frames

```
function Voss ()  {
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody()


for ( var x; x<10; x++) {
    body.appendParagraph("Below are instructions that will be cleared in some seconds");
    body.appendParagraph("On the first line, type from when to when the event is happening");
    body.appendParagraph("On the second line, type the location if it has not been programmed yet");
    body.appendParagraph("On the third line, type the Attendees");
    body.appendParagraph("On the ending lines, type the summary");
    Utilities.sleep(1000)
  }
```

And I tried

```
    body.appendParagraph("Below are instructions that will be cleared in some seconds");
    body.appendParagraph("On the first line, type from when to when the event is happening");
    body.appendParagraph("On the second line, type the location if it has not been programmed yet");
    body.appendParagraph("On the third line, type the Attendees");
    body.appendParagraph("On the ending lines, type the summary");
    Utilities.sleep(1000)
```

but they both just completed the task all at once and there was no progression at all

Answer (score 1):

I don't think apps script can be used to create such a animation efficiently because the script runs on the server and not on the browser. This is why apps script batches all your calls to a single call. You could however try [`saveAndClose`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveAndClose()) to flush pending changes in a loop.

#### Snippet:

```
for ( var x; x<10; x++) {
    /*=>*/var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    /*=>*/var body = doc.getBody();//Moved inside the loop as `doc` needs to be opened again
    body.appendParagraph("Below are instructions that will be cleared in some seconds");
    body.appendParagraph("On the first line, type from when to when the event is happening");
    body.appendParagraph("On the second line, type the location if it has not been programmed yet");
    body.appendParagraph("On the third line, type the Attendees");
    body.appendParagraph("On the ending lines, type the summary");
    /*=>*/doc.saveAndClose();//Added
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
  }
```